Does harmonic decomposition hold also for power series?
Harmonic decomposition means that you can decompose the set of polynomials $P[x]$ as
$$
P[x]=\bigoplus_{k=0}^\infty\bigoplus_{l=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}|x|^{2l}\mathcal{H}_{k-2l},
$$
where $\mathcal{H}_l$ is the set of homogeneous polynomials of degree $l$, which are harmonic.
My question is the following: can we decompose a function which is not necessarily a polynomial (but maybe it is analytic) in a similar fashon?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
